# Can i download PSN games to my Pc then transfer them to the console?

Tags: pc, psn, ps-vita

It is possible to download the games that i bought for my PS consoles (Vita for example, on my case) from PSN and then transfering the file to the hanheld/console? **Is this somehow possible?**
I'ts taking too much time downloading the files on the console unlike when i download games or files on my computer.

If anyone knows please tell me,

Thanks in regard.

*Edit: or able to connect via USB or something my Vita to a Computer to share internet? (i'm not really into this, so i don't know)*

Comment: It's going to be slow regardless. You cannot download titles directly to your PC, only transfer to/from the consoles. The transfer would be extra slow due to the added encryption that has to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short: No. 
It has to do with PlayStation security as well as making the games and consoles harder to hack, etc. This said, it should NOT matter if you are downloading something on your PC or your console as long as they are on the same network.